# The RESTful Way to Write the routes.rb for OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, omniauth

Currently I set the config/routes.rb for OmniAuth as follows:

```
match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#callback"
match "/logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => :logout
```

Are there any ways to set up routes.rb for OmniAuth with more RESTful ways like using resources or device_for?